# Position of imageview

Tags: android, layout

I want to place an image at the right of the screen width minus 20 dp on a android device.

The pseudo code for this could be:

1. Get Image from res/drawable folder.
2. Set position of image - this has to be the screen width minus 20 dp,it should calculate  the screen width and then set the position ( Is this possible in xml? )
3. Render the image.

Parts 1 & 3 are clear, but the second part I guess is tough & is where I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` as a container. Set `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_marginRight="20dp"` on an `ImageView` within this layout.

You can get more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you will need to do this in a Java class where you get the dimensions of the window, do your calculations and then set the position of the image within the `onCreate()` Method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get it with xml too:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that `android:layout_marginRight="20dp"` sets padding from right